# Selecting Row vs Column in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, computer-science, data-science

In a Pandas DataFrame, say cars, I can select and print a single column like this:

```
# country is a column
print(cars['country'])
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with a row, I failed:

```
#US is a row
print(cars['US'])
KeyError: 'US'
```

Then I tried this and it worked:

```
print(cars['US':'US'])
```

So, in Pandas DataFrame, column indexes are keys and row indexes are not?Could someone explain what's the reason for making row selection more complicated than column selection?

Comment: Look into how the [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc) accessors work

Comment: [Pandas has excellant documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: Thanks but I already read this Python documentation. Please note that I'm asking why and not how to do it. So, it's more of a question about the efficiency of python programming language instead of how to code. I'd suggest people with privileges here to understand what the question is asking before rushing to subtract reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas

```
cars['Country']
```

returns the column as a Series.  To slice a row as a Series, the equivalent command would be (assuming 'US' is an index value):

```
cars.loc['US']
```

If you do

```
cars['US':'US']
```

then you'll get the same data, but it'll be a DataFrame instead of a Series, so not quite equivalent.

Obviously, you can't have both columns and rows be referenced in the same way.  If I had a dataframe of correlations between all the stocks in the S&P 500, then your rows and index values would have the same elements. So you'd need to know whether df['AAPL'] was referring to 'AAPL' from the index or from the columns.  So df['AAPL'] is the 'AAPL' column, while df.loc['AAPL'] is the 'AAPL' row.  You could also do df.loc['AAPL', :] for the row and df.loc[:, 'AAPL'] for the column, if you prefer.

As for why they chose df['AAPL'] to be the column, my best guess is that typically dates are listed as the rows, so it's more common to select a column of data to do some operation on than it is to select a row.  However slicing rows is just as easy as columns, so there really isn't much difference except a few keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize that there was a difference between cars['US':'US'] and cars.loc['US']. Thanks to you, I'll never forget from now on.